# Show that a function is a solution to a differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**My problem**

Given $$x(t)=x_Te^{-a(T-t)}-\int_t^T e^{-a(v-t)} b\,dv$$ , $$x_T=x(T)=constant$$ Show that x(t) is a solution to 
$$\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)+b $$ 
a and b are constants

**My attempt to solution** 
$$\dot{x}(t)=ax_Te^{-a(T-t)}-\int_t^T ae^{-a(v-t)} b\,dv=a(x_Te^{-a(T-t)}-\int_t^T e^{-a(v-t)} b\,dv)=ax(t)$$

I don't see where I can get the b from.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is $b$ here a given constant?

Comment: No, a and b are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Can't $b$ even be any function?

Comment: You didn't differentiate the integral correctly, you need to use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 1):

You may use
$$
\partial_t\int\limits^t_T e^{-a(v-t)}bdv = \partial_t\left(e^{at}\int\limits^t_T e^{-av}bdv\right) = \int\limits^t_T e^{-av}bdv\left(\partial_te^{at}\right)+e^{at}\left(\partial_t\int\limits^t_T e^{-av}bdv\right)\\ = ae^{at}\int\limits^t_T e^{-av}bdv+e^{at}be^{-at} = ae^{at}\int\limits^t_T e^{-av}bdv + b
$$
where we used the product rule and $\partial_t\int\limits^t_u f(x)dx = f(t)$. Also note: $-\int\limits^t_u f(x)dx = \int\limits_t^u f(x)dx$.